# How to get my function to pass on keyword agurments to underlining plot function of Plots

Tags: julia

When I got my experimental results, I wish to plot the scatter graph. So I want to create a function to make it easier

```
using Plots

# result is an array of tuples (time,velocity)
experimental_result = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,3)]

function myplot(arrayoftuple)
    len = length(arrayoftuple)
    x = [ arrayoftuple[k][1] for k in 1:len ]
    y = [ arrayoftuple[k][2] for k in 1:len ]
    plot(x,y)
end

myplot(experimental_result)
```

Now how to I modify the function myplot so that I can pass in any keyword arguements to the underlining plot function. I am refering to keyword arguments like title="my experimental result"

Answer (score 0):

You can provide kwargs in the outer function and call the same from inner function as below.

```
using Plots

# result is an array of tuples (time,velocity)
experimental_result = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,3)]


function myplot(arrayoftuple;kwargs...)
    len = length(arrayoftuple)
    x = [ arrayoftuple[k][1] for k in 1:len ]
    y = [ arrayoftuple[k][2] for k in 1:len ]
    plot(x,y;kwargs...)
end

myplot(experimental_result;[(:xlabel,"x"),(:title ,"my experimental result")]...)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I want to pass any (that means all possible) keyword arguments to plot function underneath

Comment: When you are calling your `myplot` function, you can use kwargs as usual (no need for the list of pairs). `myplot(experimental_result; color=:black, xlabel="x")`

Answer (score 0):

With Plots, the correct answer is to write a `recipe`, see https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/recipes/. Keywords are passed automatically by recipes. 
But it's hard for me to tell what recipe is best for your mwe, as `plot(experimental_results)` already works out of the box. If you update your example to something more close to what you actually have I can show you how to write a recipe for it.